# Regular expression to match path in bash condition

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I'm looking to write a regular expression to match the following paths.

```
puts/push/1234/request
puts/push/57689/request
puts/push/123/request
puts/push/4567/request
puts/push/34/request
```

Have a variable name **Targetpath** and any of the above path could be it's value.   I have the following  conditional expression to perform the match.

```
if [[ $Targetpath =~ puts/push/*/request ]]; then echo 1; else echo 0; fi
```

But the match is not happening and getting 0 echod to the terminal always

How the above command should be modified to perform the correct match.

Comment: Use `if [[ $Targetpath =~ puts/push/[^/]+/request ]];` (if you plan to match any text but `/` in place of your `*`) or `if [[ $Targetpath =~ puts/push/[0-9]+/request ]];` (if you intend to match digits where your `*` is)

Comment: `=~` is used for regex and what you have is called glob match. Just use: `$Targetpath == puts/push/*/request` to make it work.

Comment: So what is the correct behavior? Do you want to match `puts/push/abcd/blah/1234/request`? Do you want to match `puts/push/abcde/request`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan to match any text but `/` in place of your `*` you can use

```sh
if [[ $Targetpath =~ puts/push/[^/]+/request ]];
```

Note that `[^/]+` is a negated bracket expression that matches one or more (since `+` in POSIX ERE is a *one or more* quantifier) chars other than a `/` char.

Or, if you intend to match digits where your `*` is:

```sh
if [[ $Targetpath =~ puts/push/[0-9]+/request ]];
```

Here, `[0-9]+` (or `[[:digit:]]+`) matches one or more digits.

Here is a [quick demo](https://ideone.com/aeibwz):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
Targetpath='puts/push/1234/request'
rx='puts/push/[0-9]+/request'
if [[ "$Targetpath" =~ $rx ]]; then echo 1; else echo 0; fi
# => 1
```

Note you do not need to escape slashes in this case as `/` are not regex delimiters here (in `sed` commands, you need to escape `/` if `/` is used as a regex delimiter char).

In case you do not care what char appear between `puts/push/` and `/request`, simply use glob matching:

```sh
if [[ "$Targetpath" == puts/push/*/request ]]; then echo 1; else echo 0; fi
```

Note the `==` operator and `*` that matches any text. However, note that glob patterns match the whole text/string, so you might need `*` on both ends of it, too.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the following regex string, modify the number of numerals if needed

```
regex="puts\/push\/[0-9]{2,}\/request"
if [[ $var =~ $regex ]]; then echo 1; else echo 0; fi
```

Answer (score 1):

As I commented this requirement doesn't need regex. It can be done entirely in glob (or `extglob`):

**Case 1:** If you want to validate starting and ending part only then use:

```sh
[[ $Targetpath == puts/push/*/request ]]
```

---

**Case 2:** If you want to validate starting and ending part and allowing only digits in the middle part:

```sh
# enable extended glob
shopt -s extglob 
[[ $Targetpath == puts/push/+([[:digit:]])/request ]]
```

---

**Case 3:** If you want to validate starting and ending part and allowing only 1+ of any non-`/` characters the middle part:

```sh
# enable extended glob
shopt -s extglob 
[[ $Targetpath == puts/push/+([!/])/request ]]
```